# FormData append doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-data

In jQuery code,

```
var formData = new FormData($('#content-submit')[0]);
        formData.append("Title", $("input[name=Title]").val());
        formData.append("Url", $("input[name=Url]").val());
        formData.append("Content", $("textarea[name=Content]").text());
        formData.append("Genre", $("input[name=Genre]").val());
        formData.append("File", $("input[name=File]")[0].files[0]);
        console.log(formData);
```

But console.log says

```
FormData {}
```

So I think that FormData append method doesn't work. Are there other things that I should do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`FormData` can't be inspected from the web developer console. You can only use them to create key value pairs to be sent.

If you want to debug it, you may do this,

```
for (var p of formData) {
  console.log(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`formData.getAll('keyName')` will return an array of all the values stored in a specific key. This can be viewed from your Web Dev Console.